# Pandas dataframfe TypeError: is there a problem with indexing using int?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

For the next code:

```
1_df = pd.read_csv("1.csv")
2_df = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
3_df = pd.read_csv("3.csv")

GT_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = {'text', 'labelsum', 'label_value'})
row_count = 0

for x in range(1_df.shape[0]):
    if 1_df.iloc[x,3] + 2_df.iloc[x,3] + 3_df.iloc[x,3] == 0:
        GT_df.loc[row_count,0]=1_df.loc[x,0]
        GT_df.iloc[row_count,1]=1_df.iloc[x,2] + 2_df.iloc[x,2] + 3_df.iloc[x,2]
        if GT_df.iloc[row_count,1]>1:
            GT_df.iloc[row_count,2]=1
        else: 
            GT_df.iloc[row_count,2]=0
        GT_row_count +=1

print(GT_df)
```

I get the next error:

> TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index' with these indexers [0] of class 'int'

Any ideas what is the cause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have incorrect variable names, Python doesn't accept variables with numbers at the start. are you able to show your input data and what you're trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

`iloc` and `loc` have subtle differences. If you are going to use positions to index, then use `iloc` and if you are going to use column names or conditions to index, then use `loc`.